# IIS 7 site binding, host name must be empty

Tags: iis-7, web, hostname

I am trying to set web site on IIS 7. I have look up many tutorial like this on 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772350(WS.10).aspx
and they all say that it should be possible to add website by entering site name, physical path and bindings information.

My problem is that the website can only work if I leave host name box empty. That means that I can run only one website under default port 80.

If I put some host name and try to access it by typing host name in browser, the browser reports "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

Is this normal behavior on IIS 7, do I need to do some additional installation or configuration ? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> you must register the host headers with the appropriate name resolution system. If you website is only for local hosting, you can register the host header in the hosts file(%windir%/System32/drivers/etc). Then, you will be able test your website on local machine via host header name.

And also you can use different ports....not only 88
I often use this way...

Comment: do you have a reference for this?

Comment: http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/mark-newnam/how-to-set-up-site-bindings-in-internet-information-services-iis/